# can't save custom attribute in order table during checkout

Tags: checkout, magento-1

I've created a custom order column but when i try to populate it during checkout it doesn't save data. (Else if I edit order in backend my custom column is populated):
/app/code/local/Radicis/Managecommunities/sql/radicis_managecommunities_setup/

```
$installer = new Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup;
$table = $installer->getTable('sales/quote');
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($table, 'pickup_date', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    'comment' => 'Pickup Date'
    )
);

$table = $installer->getTable('sales/order');
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($table, 'pickup_date', array(
    'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_DATETIME,
    'comment' => 'Pickup Date'
)
);
```

config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<modules>
    <Radicis_Managecommunities>
        <version>0.0.13</version>
    </Radicis_Managecommunities>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <radicis_managecommunities>
            <class>Radicis_Managecommunities_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>radicis_managecommunities_resource</resourceModel>
        </radicis_managecommunities>
        <radicis_managecommunities_resource>
            <class>Radicis_Managecommunities_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <community>
                    <table>radicis_community</table>
                </community>
                <pickupgroup>
                    <table>radicis_pickupgroups</table>
                </pickupgroup>
                <communitypickupgroup>
                    <table>radicis_communities_pickupgroups</table>
                </communitypickupgroup>
            </entities>
        </radicis_managecommunities_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <radicis_managecommunities_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Radicis_Managecommunities</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </radicis_managecommunities_setup>
        <radicis_managecommunities_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </radicis_managecommunities_write>
        <radicis_managecommunities_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </radicis_managecommunities_read>
    </resources>

    <blocks>
        <radicis_managecommunities>
            <class>Radicis_Managecommunities_Block</class>
        </radicis_managecommunities>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage>Radicis_Managecommunities_Block_Checkout_Onepage</onepage>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <radicis_managecommunities>
            <class>Radicis_Managecommunities_Helper</class>
        </radicis_managecommunities>
    </helpers>
    <fieldsets>
        <checkout_onepage_quote>
            <pickup_date>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </pickup_date>
        </checkout_onepage_quote>
        <sales_convert_quote>
            <community_id>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </community_id>
            <invoice_needed>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </invoice_needed>
            <pickup_date>
                <to_order>*</to_order>
            </pickup_date>
        </sales_convert_quote>
    </fieldsets>
    <events>


        <sales_order_save_before>
            <observers>
                <managecommunities>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Radicis_Managecommunities_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>savePickupDate</method>
                </managecommunities>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_before>
    </events>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <radicis_managecommunities before="Mage_Adminhtml">Radicis_Managecommunities_Adminhtml</radicis_managecommunities>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <radicis_managecommunities>
                <file>radicis_managecommunities.xml</file>
            </radicis_managecommunities>
        </updates>
    </layout>

    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Radicis_Managecommunities>
                <files>
                    <default>Radicis_Managecommunities.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Radicis_Managecommunities>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>

<frontend>
    <routers>
        <radicis_managecommunities>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Radicis_Managecommunities</module>
                <frontName>community</frontName>
            </args>
        </radicis_managecommunities>
        <opc>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Radicis_Managecommunities before="IWD_Opc">Radicis_Managecommunities_Opc</Radicis_Managecommunities>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </opc>
    </routers>

    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Radicis_Managecommunities>
                <files>
                    <default>Radicis_Managecommunities.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Radicis_Managecommunities>
        </modules>
    </translate>

    <layout>
        <updates>
            <radicis_managecommunities>
                <file>radicis_managecommunities.xml</file>
            </radicis_managecommunities>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
</config>
```

Radicis_Managecommunities_Opc_JsonController - SaveShippingMethodAction:

```
public function saveShippingMethodAction(){
    if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
        return;
    }
    $responseData = array();

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {

        $this->checkNewslatter();

        $data = Mage::helper('radicis_managecommunities')->getDefaultShippingMethod();
        $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($data);
        /*
         $result will have erro data if shipping method is empty
        */
        if(!$result) {
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method',
                array('request'=>$this->getRequest(),
                    'quote'=>$this->getOnepage()->getQuote())
            );

            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
            $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

            $responseData['review'] = $this->_getReviewHtml();
            $responseData['grandTotal'] = Mage::helper('opc')->getGrandTotal();
            /*$result['update_section'] = array(
                    'name' => 'payment-method',
                    'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
            );*/
        }
        $coreSession = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        $currentPickupDate = $coreSession->getCommunityPickupDate();

        $quote = $this->getOnepage()->getQuote();
        $quote->setData('pickup_date',$currentPickupDate.' 00:00:00');
        $quote->save();
        $responseData['pickup_date'] = $quote->getData('pickup_date');
        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();

        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json', true);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($responseData));
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I created a workaround using an observer: checkout_submit_all_after and then in my observer I wrote flat query retrieving last inserted order and updating it but this is not elegant, i don't like it.